# Определения вендорнаго префикса браузера

Tags: javascript, css, css3, angularjs, кроссбраузерность

Есть сайт написанный с использованием `AngularJS` и анимация на `JS`.
В анимации используется `transform` ,а как мы знаем без вендорных префиксов не во всех браузерах будет работать.

На сколько я знаю `jquery` сам определяет и подставляет нужный префикс при добавлении стиля, но не хочется подключать `jquery`, только из-за этого, хватает и [`jqLite`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).
Так же не хочется писать все префиксы сразу при добавлении стиля через `jqLite`.

Может кто знает как это сделано в `jquery`?

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно определить какой префикс нужно ставит для браузера через который открыт сайт?

Comment: Вы `transition` указываете в CSS, верно? По крайне мере, [я так делаю](https://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/kpw04fza/2/) для angular анимации.

Comment: @romeo, нет там CSS указывается через `jqLite` (`angular.element`), там анимация посложнее и сделано не через angular анимацию.

Comment: Кто-нибудь знает) В `jQuery` использован примерно такой же метод как и у меня в ответе, просто я его упростил для частного случая. Ответ дополнил описанием того как это делается в `jQuery`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из способов - проверить у элемента наличие нужного свойства с префиксом (или без):

```
function getTransformType() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var types = ['transform', 'MozTransform', 'WebkitTransform', 'какие там еще нужны'];
    for (var i = 0; i < types.length; ++i) {
        if (typeof div.style[types[i]] != 'undefined') {
            return types[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

`jQuery` делает проверку похожим образом. Там хранится массив:

`cssPrefixes = [ "Webkit", "O", "Moz", "ms" ];`

Перед тем как применять на элементе свойство, там выполняется поиск правильного имени:

```
// Return a css property mapped to a potentially vendor prefixed property
function vendorPropName( style, name ) {
    // Shortcut for names that are not vendor prefixed
    if ( name in style ) {
        return name;
    }

    // Check for vendor prefixed names
    var capName = name[0].toUpperCase() + name.slice(1),
        origName = name,
        i = cssPrefixes.length;

    while ( i-- ) {
        name = cssPrefixes[ i ] + capName;
        if ( name in style ) {
            return name;
        }
    }
    return origName;
}
```

Эта функция возвращает "правильное" свойство. Суть точно такая же как я описал выше. Окончательно имя свойства там выбирается  так:

```
name = jQuery.cssProps[ origName ] || ( jQuery.cssProps[ origName ] = vendorPropName( style, origName ) );
```

То есть они кэшируют запросы, чтобы каждый раз не тестить, на необходимость префикса.

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой подробный ответ, даже разобрали как это сделано в `jQuery`, ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: И да, у вас функция не рабочая в типах не должно быть `transform`, так как он всегда будет. Убираем его из массива и заменяем `return null;` на `return 'transform';` ;)

Comment: @Mr_Epic, `transform` будет не всегда, а будет он, когда свойство работает без префикса. `return null;` нужен для того, чтобы сказать, что поддержки нету, например, если это ie9.

Answer (score 0):

1. `transform` уже давно [работает без префиксов](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform), кроме сафари.
2. Можно перечислить нужные префиксы - в css от них хуже не будет.
3. Если речь не о css, а об обработчике завершения анимации, то там делать гораздо хитрее надо, потому что вполне могут вызваться несколько - с префиксом и без.

Comment: 1) сафари как раз мне и нужно :) 2)Анимация на JS 3)Анимация элемента получается за счёт изменения `transform` у элемента(через JS).